# C boucle with kill and wait

Tags: c, signals, sleep, kill, thread-sleep

I have a problem with my c program , I would like to send a signal to many processus but I can't create a boucle with wait betwwen two kill
How to do that ?
Thank you ;)

```
void * functionThreadPartie(void *pVoid) {

pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&unMutex);
printf("INFO : declenchement de la partie\n");

struct data_t *memoryShared;

while (memoryShared->start==1){

    memoryShared=getSharedMemory(1056);
    printf("DEBUG : a qui de jouer ? %d\n",memoryShared->aQuiDeJouer);

    int aQuiDeJouer=memoryShared->aQuiDeJouer;
    if(aQuiDeJouer==NB_JOUEURS){
        kill(memoryShared->idProcessus[aQuiDeJouer],SIGUSR1);
        memoryShared->aQuiDeJouer=1; // Remise en place du joeur
        printf("DEBUG : joueur suivant  %d\n",memoryShared->aQuiDeJouer);
    }else{
        kill(memoryShared->idProcessus[aQuiDeJouer],SIGUSR1);
        memoryShared->aQuiDeJouer++; // Remise en place du joeur
        printf("DEBUG : joueur suivant  %d\n",memoryShared->aQuiDeJouer);
    }
    detachSharedMemory(memoryShared);
    wait(2000);
}

pthread_exit(0);
```

}

Comment: Upon initial entry to the loop, you access `memoryShared` while it is indeterminate. If `detachSharedMemory()` does what its name suggests then on the second and subsequent iterations you are testing an invalid pointer.  Why are you detaching and reattaching anyway?  I would expect the program to attach once only, before entering the loop, and to detach once only, after the loop terminates.

Comment: Also, "boucle" did not translate, but I think you mean "loop".

Comment: I will have change ! but it doesn't work , I have add flag `memoryShared=getSharedMemory(1056);
    int flag=memoryShared->start;
    detachSharedMemory(memoryShared);
    while (flag==1)    and setup in moop that :   flag=memoryShared->start;`

Comment: I'm not entirely following the modifications you describe, but one thing that is clear is that you have not lost your determination to detach the shared memory quickly.  I still don't understand why.

Comment: Okay , I detach my shared memory because during my loop ( sleep ) an other program use my shared memory ! I

Comment: It's *shared* memory.  More than one program can have it attached at the same time, and that's normal.  But now that you mention it, it *is* an issue to sleep while holding the mutex locked.  On the other hand, your `wait()` call does not make sense.  Doe read [its docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitid.2.html) to see its signature and what it actually does.